# Understanding stages in ramping-arrival-rate

Tags: k6

Here is my sample executor:

```
executor: 'ramping-arrival-rate',
timeUnit: '1m',
stages: [
    { target: 10000, duration: '1m' },
    { target: 20000, duration: '1m' },
    { target: 30000, duration: '1m' },
    { target: 40000, duration: '1m' },
    { target: 50000, duration: '1m' }
]
```

How should I understand the arrival-rate in the above, lets say, if the test starts at 10am?

```
1. 10.00.00sec - 10.00.59sec: 10000 Requests (Total Req at the end of this stage: 10000)
2. 10.01.00sec - 10.01.59sec: 10000 Requests (Total Req at the end of this stage: 20000)
3. 10.02.00sec - 10.02.59sec: 10000 Requests (Total Req at the end of this stage: 30000)
4. 10.03.00sec - 10.03.59sec: 10000 Requests (Total Req at the end of this stage: 40000)
5. 10.04.00sec - 10.04.59sec: 10000 Requests (Total Req at the end of this stage: 50000)
```

Is my understanding correct?

Also, is there any way I can randomize my request. As an example, in my application, the req per min keep varying:

10.00.00am - 4394, 10.01.00am - 4000, 10.02.00am - 3422 and so on. I would like to send a random request always in the range of [3000-4500] per min?
Does any executor provide this?

I’m asking as I have to prepare a model using ramping-arrival-rate to match my app request pattern. Any suggestion on this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your first assumption is incorrect. The target of consecutive stages is interpolated linearly until the *end of the stage*. To get your expected pattern (10k after 1m, 20k after 2m), you would need the following stage definition:

```
stages: [
    { target: 10000, duration: '0s' },
    { target: 10000, duration: '1m' },
    { target: 20000, duration: '0s' },
    { target: 20000, duration: '1m' },
    { target: 30000, duration: '0s' },
    { target: 30000, duration: '1m' },
    { target: 40000, duration: '0s' },
    { target: 40000, duration: '1m' },
    { target: 50000, duration: '0s' },
    { target: 50000, duration: '1m' }
]
```

See [Arrival-rate VU allocation](https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/scenarios/concepts/arrival-rate-vu-allocation/) for details, especially the section [Iteration duration affects the necessary allocation](https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/scenarios/concepts/arrival-rate-vu-allocation/#iteration-duration-affects-the-necessary-allocation). Also related: https://k6.io/docs/examples/instant-load-increase/.

Here's a simple demo which shows this. The default function can be as simple as `export default function() {/*nop*/}`, since the number of iterations of a test is already tracked out of the box by k6.

Given 2 stages with a rate of 5 rps and 10 rps, respectively:

```
{ target: 5, duration: '10s' },
{ target: 10, duration: '10s' },
```

Your expectation was 150 iterations (`10*5 + 10*10`); however the actual number of iterations is 100 (`10*(0+5)/2 + 10*(5+10)/2 = 10*2.5 + 10*7.5 = 100` – remember: linear interpolation):

```
iterations...........: 100 4.999722/s
```

Compare that to the following stage definition, which avoids the linear interpolation and immediately sets the desired target rate:

```
{ target: 5, duration: '0s' },
{ target: 5, duration: '10s' },
{ target: 10, duration: '0s' },
{ target: 10, duration: '10s' },
```

Now, the formula of total iterations becomes `0*(0+5)/2 + 10*(5+5)/2 + 0*(5+10)/2 + 10*(10+10)/2 = 0 + 10*5 + 0 + 10*10 = 150`; and indeed you'll get the desired number of iterations:

```
iterations...........: 149 7.449772/s
```

---

Regarding your second question (which should be [a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) really):

The `stages` array does not need to be defined statically. You can use any JavaScript function to populate it, e.g.:

```
export const options = {
  scenarios: {
    realistic: {
      // ...
      stages: generateStages(3000, 4500),
    }
  }
};

function generateStages(min, max) {
  // calculate stages, e.g. using `Math.abs(Math.sin())`, then shift and scale appropriately
  return [ ... ];
}
```

Comment: Thanks @knittl. What is the purpose of having a stage with 0s ?

Comment: @user8479984 a stage of 0s is required to get your required behavior, i.e. _immediately_ use the new rate instead of linearly interpolating the rate until the end of the current rate.

Comment: @user8479984 I have extended my answer with additional links and have provided an example.